# Error while connecting outlook in azure logic apps. Error details : The tenant for tenant guid '***' does not exist

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to follow the below link
https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2018/03/add-email-notification-in-azure-data.html

In the a3 step, I am getting this error when I sign in to my outlook account.
My outlook account is the same which I have used for creating my Azure account.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have selected an [Office 365 Outlook connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-office365-outlook), which should be used when you have an Office 365 account. Most of the time, these are used to host email on a custom domain.

> With Azure Logic Apps and the Office 365 Outlook connector, you can create automated tasks and workflows that manage your work or school account by building logic apps.

If you need to connect to outlook.com, use the [Outlook.com connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-outlook).

> With Azure Logic Apps and the Outlook.com connector, you can create automated tasks and workflows that manage your @outlook.com or @hotmail.com account by building logic apps.

[image: Outlook.com connector]